# What is the role of getClass().getResource in loading fxml file?

Tags: java

`load()` method of `FXMLLoader` class is used to load FXML file. Then what is `getClass().getResource()` is doing in

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainFXML.fxml"));
```

What is wrong with

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(("MainFXML.fxml"));
```

Comment: Reads the file from the classpath. `FXMLLoader.load(("MainFXML.fxml"));` Loads a file from Filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Class.[getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) is used to retrieve the `URL` of a resource that can be found in the classpath .

`FXMLLoader` then [loads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-) the file with this URL .

[FXMLLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) has two way of loading , by `URL` or by `InputStream`.

If you want to use a `File`, try this :

```
FXMLLoader.load(new FileInputStream(new File("MainFXML.fxml")));
```

And try-catch the possible exceptions that may occur.

Comment: there are more ways than just two :)

Comment: @xenteros  : from the above linked documentation, I see no `load` method taking anything else than an `URL` or an `InputStream` to get to the resource, do you have more information ?

Answer (score 0):

Method `load` has different implementations but none of them takes a `String` as a parameter.

`getClass().getResource("MainFXML.fxml");` returns an `URL`. `URL` is a valid parameter for `load`. That's it.

So summarizing, there is no implementation of `load(String)`.

You can retrieve the URL in different ways. They are described in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html) official tutorial.